# How to use dotnet pack with AppVeyor?

Tags: .net, nuget, pack, appveyor

I'm automating my .NET Standard projects (VS 2017's new csproj format) to generate nuget packages after building.

The thing is that I want all the projects in the solution to follow the version of my AppVeyor build, not the version that is set inside the Package properties of the csprojs (that is defaulted to 1.0.0).

Another thing to take into account is that my projects have references between them and should keep the AppVeyor build version, too.

Is there an easy way to do it? How?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the version as an MSBuild property to `dotnet pack`:

```
dotnet pack MyProject.csproj --configuration Release /p:Version="1.2.3"
```

(this works for `dotnet build` too)

Here's an example in the [FakeItEasy build script](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/blob/43c6b1f4317577e70032804cdd86402e15722521/build.csx#L175).

To get the AppVeyor build number, use the `APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION` [environment variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/).

> Another thing to take into account is that my projects have references between them and should keep the AppVeyor build version, too.

This shouldn't be an issue, because you don't specify a version in the `<ProjectReference>` element.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** [.NET Core .csproj files patching](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#net-core-csproj-files-patching) and [automatic nuget packaging for .NET Core projects](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-phase/#packaging-net-core-nuget-libraries) works now.

---

There are few options:

Do manual patching of .NET Standard `.csproj` file with PowerShell. In this sample we update version, but you can update other settings too this way.

```
$xmlPath = "$env:appveyor_build_folder\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
$xml = [xml](get-content $xmlPath)
$propertyGroup = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup | Where { $_.Version}
$propertyGroup.Version = $env:appveyor_build_version
$xml.Save($xmlPath)
msbuild %appveyor_build_folder%\MyProject\MyProject.csproj /t:pack
```

or if you want to keep using `.nuspec` file, you can pack with command like this:

```
msbuild %appveyor_build_folder%\MyProject\MyProject.csproj /t:pack /p:Configuration=%CONFIGURATION%;NuspecFile=MyProject\MyProject.nuspec;PackageVersion=%APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%
```

Sure you can use `dotnet pack` but we feel that going forward `msbuild` will remain main tool, so we try to do all scripting using it.

Needless to say that we in AppVeyor should make this scripting unneeded, we track this in https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1404.

Comment: I don't think csproj should have a `Version` attribute. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017), it should be `PackageVersion`.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj), for `PackageVersion`, *default is the value of $(Version), that is, of the property Version in the project*. So as I understand `Version` is still valid, but `PackageVersion` is more specific to Nuget packaging. **Addition**: I think that for automatic patching in AppVeyor we should propose options to patch both and actually patch what really exists in `.csproj`

Comment: This works great for `*.csproj` files, but does it not also work for `*.fsproj` files?  I can get the assembly info patching to work for both, but `dotnet pack` only seems to run for the `*.csproj` files.